# Why don't I see Twitter's homescreen widget on my Android?

Tags: twitter, app-widgets

When I go to add widgets to my home screen, I don't have any widget from Twitter available. Other widgets are appearing in the widget list, can be added, and work fine. Just nothing from Twitter.

What could possibly be causing this?

I am on Android 6, but it couldn't possibly be too old, as i have an even older device running Android 4.3 where the Twitter widget is available. I have the Twitter app installed, I am logged into it, I can open it and use it. The only thing that is missing is their widget for my home screen.

I have tried removing the app and installing it again, logging back in again, restarted the device a couple times, but the widget just doesn't offer, neither for the default launcher, nor in Nova Launcher.

Comment: try to login twitter using chrome. after logged in tap on three dots on top-right portion of chrome and select 'Add to Home Screen'. This will act as twitter app icon. I am using the same, I don't have twitter app installed, but placed like this. By, tapping icon, it loads twitter in chrome, for your case, I think it will redirect action to twitter app.

Comment: @RahulGopi Like i wrote in my original post, the app works fine. It's the widget that is missing, and your suggestion will not give me the widget, nor an alternative to it.

Comment: Okay. Try with any other launcher. Or uninstall and reinstall twitter app and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, the Twitter widget is gone.

The Twitter widget was removed from service in the newer versions since release 6.8.0. See the report dated July 26, 2015 from [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/2016/07/27/twitter-removes-homescreen-widget-support-latest-alpha/). It is possible the version you are maintaining on the earlier OS was never updated (or can't be) to a widget-less version.

My Samsung S8 carries the latest Twitter App and no widget available, regardless of launcher. (I use Nova, but confirmed this too, by reverting to the default)

Comment: Thanks for the info! Never would have crossed my mind that that would be the case, especially with 3rd-party apps popping up to offer a homescreen twitter widget. I have now solved my need for the widget by installing the older version of their app. Cheers!